# limitar datos traídos de una api

Tags: javascript

Estoy trayendo un info de una api, escribo un numero en la barra de búsqueda y me muestra 3 elementos correctamente, ahora necesito reiniciar el value de ese input porque si cambio el numero digamos por 5 me mostraría 8 elementos en total, tres anteriores + cinco de la nueva búsqueda, como puedo reiniciar la variable?

he tratado así news_quantity_val = "";

pero me sigue mostrando los resultados de la antigua búsqueda + los de la nueva búsqueda

como podría hacer para que no acumule los resultados.

Gracias.

```js
var news_quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
var searhing_button = document.getElementById("searching_btn");

searhing_button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    var news_quantity_val = news_quantity.value;
    if(news_quantity_val !== ""){
        
        async function chuck(url){
            var getting_phrases = await fetch(url);
            var json_transform = await getting_phrases.json();
            
            var new_news = document.getElementById("news");
            var new_element = document.createElement("div");
            new_element.classList.add("news", "d-flex", "justify-content-around", "align-items-center", "mt-5", "rounded", "p-2", "shadow-sm", "mb-5"); 
            new_element.innerHTML = `<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="chuck-norris-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="m-0">id: ${json_transform.id}</p>`
            
            new_news.appendChild(new_element);    
        }

        
        for(i=0; i<news_quantity_val; i++){
            chuck("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        } 
     
    } 

});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#news h4{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#date {
    font-size: .7rem;
}

#news_id {
    font-size: .5rem;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.img-hero{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chuck Norris</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand p-0">
            <button class="navbar-toggler"  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-top: 30px;">
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 w-100">
                <input id ="quantity" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="number" placeholder="Search" style="width:92%" aria-label="Search">
                <button id="searching_btn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div id="news">
            
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="news d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center mt-5  rounded p-2 shadow-sm">
            <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="chuck-norris-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="m-0">created_at: "2020-01-05 13:42:28.664997"</p>
        </div> -->


        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">id: 123456789</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body pt-5 pb-5 pl-5 pr-5">
                    <p id="news_id" class="text-center text-muted font-italic">updated_at: 2020-01-05 13:42:25.352697</p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
                        <img src="chuck1.jpg"  alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Chuck Norris solo-ed Everest in shorts and a tank-top.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer border-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes limpiar el contenido de tu lista, dado que el metodo `appendChild` lo que hace es agregar nuevo hijos a la lista, estonces debes desaparecer los hijos anteriores con `new_news.innerHTML = ""` para que queden solo los nuevos.

Ademas que no es necesario tener tu función `chuck` declarada dentro del evento, declara abajo o arriaba así podras llamarla sin problemas ( tambien así es más legible el código).

**Código de Repuesta:**

```js
var news_quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
var searhing_button = document.getElementById("searching_btn");

searhing_button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

    var news_quantity_val = news_quantity.value;
    if(news_quantity_val !== ""){
        
        var new_news = document.getElementById("news"); 
        new_news.innerHTML = ''; /* <--VACIO EL LISTADO */           
        for(i=0; i<news_quantity_val; i++){
            chuck("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random");
        } /* <-- AGREGA NUVOS ELEMENTOS */
     
    } 

});

 async function chuck(url){
            var getting_phrases = await fetch(url);
            var json_transform = await getting_phrases.json();
            
            var new_news = document.getElementById("news");
            var new_element = document.createElement("div");
            new_element.classList.add("news", "d-flex", "justify-content-around", "align-items-center", "mt-5", "rounded", "p-2", "shadow-sm", "mb-5"); 
            new_element.innerHTML = `<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="chuck-norris-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="m-0">id: ${json_transform.id}</p>`

            
            new_news.appendChild(new_element); /* AGREGO NUEVOS ELEMENTOS*/
        }
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#news h4{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#date {
    font-size: .7rem;
}

#news_id {
    font-size: .5rem;
}

*{
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}

.img-hero{
    height: 300px;
    width: 500%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

footer{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chuck Norris</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand p-0">
            <button class="navbar-toggler"  type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" style="margin-top: 30px;">
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 w-100">
                <input id ="quantity" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="number" placeholder="Search" style="width:92%" aria-label="Search">
                <button id="searching_btn" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div id="news">
            
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="news d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center mt-5  rounded p-2 shadow-sm">
            <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="chuck-norris-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="m-0">created_at: "2020-01-05 13:42:28.664997"</p>
        </div> -->


        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-primary text-white">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">id: 123456789</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body pt-5 pb-5 pl-5 pr-5">
                    <p id="news_id" class="text-center text-muted font-italic">updated_at: 2020-01-05 13:42:25.352697</p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5 mb-5">
                        <img src="chuck1.jpg"  alt="">
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="text-center">Chuck Norris solo-ed Everest in shorts and a tank-top.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer border-0">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que debes hacer es "limpiar" el contenedor antes de agregar nuevos elementos:

```
var new_news = document.getElementById("news");
news_news.innerHTML = '';
// Aquí agregas los nuevos elementos
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes limpiar el contenedor fuera de la funcion **chuck** dado que si lo limpias dentro de la función, siempre te estará mostrando un elemento

```html
var new_news = document.getElementById("news");
new_news.innerHTML = "";

        async function chuck(url){
            var getting_phrases = await fetch(url);
            var json_transform = await getting_phrases.json();
            
            var new_element = document.createElement("div");
            new_element.classList.add("news", "d-flex", "justify-content-around", "align-items-center", "mt-5", "rounded", "p-2", "shadow-sm", "mb-5"); 
            new_element.innerHTML = `<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><img src="chuck-norris-logo.png" alt=""></div>
            <p class="m-0">id: ${json_transform.id}</p>`
            new_news.appendChild(new_element);    
        }
```